# Compiling Go Fyne on raspberry pi

Tags: go, user-interface, raspberry-pi, iot, fyne

I want to have the fyne GUI running on a raspberry PI
I followed Fyne documentation https://developer.fyne.io/started/cross-compiling and aimed at linux  arm but I could not get an EXE that would run. So I installed VS code on raspberry PI and compiled the executable there. This is not a bad idea as you need access to the GPIO whilst your developing.
But when it came time to compile and executable many problems of libraries and dependencies erupted.

`$ uname -m   : returns aarch64  == go install` compiles ok for both console and web apps.
go1.21.4
When you try to build with fyne dependencies problems start.

1. OpenGL development files are needed
   = solve with
   $  `sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev`
2. compilation process is missing the `X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h` header file, which is necessary for GLFW to work on X11-based systems like the Raspberry Pi.
   = solve with
   `$ sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxkbcommon-dev libwayland-dev libwayland-egl-backend-dev`
3. linker (ld) cannot find the library -lXxf86vm during the compilation of your Go code. This library is related to the XFree86 VidMode Extension, which is commonly used for managing screen modes in X11 environments.
   = solve with.
   `sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm-dev`

Finally I was able to produce a Fyne GUI and transpose it to a fresh Raspbian where the exe ran ok.
Although I am successful(and can develop) I don't feel confident making apps for distribution.
It feels like I am braking new ground when I want a stable CI/CD.

I went through these issues myself with very little help that I could find. I post here as my experience may help somebody, in the event that nobody can help me find a better way.

One needs to develop on the raspberry up an until a raspberry simulator is available.
So it makes sense that fyne should have a working solution for raspberry with out users going through dependency hell. Please could anyone help me find a smoother more dependable path.

I tried many combinations of dependency references where I was expecting all dependencies as needed by the fine package to come with the fyne package or be noted in documentation. I want to support fyne and go , but to do that I need to get up and running myself first. There are may uses for fyne in IOT devices and mobile edge case computing. I wish better documentation and home my feedback can help in that.

Comment: There seem to be some instructions here https://developer.fyne.io/started/cross-compiling if they are missing details you would be better off contacting the fyne / fyne-cross projects themselves

Comment: Fyne-cross for Linux arm should work (it does for me). I’m not sure where you looked for help but the team is ready to support on email, Slack, Discord, Matrix, Twitter/X and Mastodon. All linked from https://fyne.io#contact.

Comment: Ok I understand the confusion = Fyne-cross may work but in order to test and develop with raspberry pi ->  i/o and usb etc one needs to develop and compile  on the raspberry its self in order to be on the same os device as the electronics that is being developed is connected. Fyne is the instrument panel GIU for local device electronics.